# Ubuntu 12.10 can't boot on HP Mini 210-4000 and brightness problem

Tags: 12.10, 13.10, intel-graphics, brightness, hp

I've problem installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP Mini 210-4000 notebook with spec Intel Atom 2800 and Intel GMA 3600, after installation finish, and rebooting, the GRUB bootloader appear without any text just only purple background and then enter to the Ubuntu with black blank screen.

After that I'm trying installing Ubuntu 11.10 and succesfully to the home screen but the brightness can't be configured.

How to figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This because Ubuntu 12.10 using PAE kernel while HP Mini-4000 doesn't support PAE, so that It only ca be installed with Ubuntu 12.04, but still cannot configure the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

While there are issue with BOTH **12.10** and **13.04**, the *HP Mini 210 4000* series does run with Ubuntu **13.10** quite well.

---

The various issue with **12.10** (and **13.04**) includes the Intel-graphics driver, and various cross effects causing crashes and background task *lockup* issues.

I gave up and used **12.04 LTS**, *prior to **13.10** being released*.

Comment: So maybe this due to lack of Intel mesa graphic driver? I saw intel mesa being in heavy development (reading at phoronix).
btw, you have tried it on hp mini 210-4000 yourself bro?